# Python: Printing the sum of all items in a list via functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**My Objective:** To find and print the sum of all the items in the list via function

**My Code:**

```
def list_sum(x):
    if type(x)!='list':
        print("Invalid List item!")
    if type(x)=='list':
        list_length = len(x)
        total = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range (list_length):
            total +=x[i]
            i+=1
        print("The sum of all items in the list is: ",total)

samples = [1,3,5,6,8,45,67,89]

list_sum(samples)
```

**My Output:**

```
<class 'list'>
Invalid List item!
```

**Expected:**
224

Why am I getting the output I am getting?

Comment: why not : `sum([1,3,5,6,8,45,67,89])` ?

Comment: How about `sum(x)`?

Comment: `type()` does not return a string, so your `type(x)!='list'` test is **always true**.

Comment: True guys, I can use the built in function .... but I was kind of playing around. I wanted to create a function from scratch.

Comment: replacing `type(x)=='list'` by `type(x)==list` will make your function work

Comment: @SebastienD: and still would be a bad idea.

Comment: Next, `for i in range(...)` will set `i` to a new value each loop iteration. Using `i+=1` in the loop is entirely useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
if type(x) != list
```

not

```
if type(x) != 'list'
```

Comment: Or you could use isinstance(x, list)